# iMovie: select parts I want to use

Tags: imovie

I'm new to iMovie

I have imported the raw footage I want to edit

Here is the noob question:

**How do I select the parts I want to use?**

It seems, in older versions of iMovie, this was done simply by marking (click and drag to select) the part, and then move it down to timeline

How is it done now?

*Macbook Pro 15" retina 2012 with Yosemite*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new project (on top), with or without a theme. Then the timeline will be on bottom and the iMovie library on top. Now you can drag pieces in, just like before.

Comment: Please read my question again ;) It's not like before (before, you could easily select the right parts first). How do I select the pieces I want to use? Say I have 23 minutes of footage. I want to use 5 small parts of that. EDIT: oh.. this is your first answer...

Comment: Does [this](http://i.imgur.com/oAvF5PB.gif) help?

Comment: No. You use the old version of iMovie? (where click and drag to select is possible)

Comment: Oops, you're right, I didn't notice that it hadn't updated together with Yosemite, my bad.

Comment: damn why did they change that? that was so intuitive and perfect..

Comment: @mowgli, I just updated to the new version, and the behaviour is still the [same](http://i.imgur.com/KeO478A.gif). This is version 10.0.6.

Comment: I believe I had a bug yesterday. Today it works with click & drag. Strange